# Sort Dictionary Alphabetically Cannot assign value of type '[(key: String, value: AnyObject)]' to type 'Dictionary<String, AnyObject>?'

Tags: swift

I have this Dictionary, which I am getting from a web service:

```
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:.allowFragments) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
```

and now I am trying to sort them alphabetically like so:

```
self.appDelegate.communityArray = json.sorted(by: {$0.0 < $1.0})
```

But I get this error:

> Cannot assign value of type '[(key: String, value: AnyObject)]' to
>   type 'Dictionary?'

What am I doing wrong?

This is how I am defining communityArray:

```
var communityArray: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>?
```

Comment: Looks like you mistakenly declared a variable named `communityArray` as a dictionary instead of an array.

Comment: A dictionary is unordered by definition and cannot be sorted. What you got is an array of tuples. That's what the error message is telling you.

Comment: ... and a Swift 3+ JSON dictionary is always `[String:Any]`, never `[String:AnyObject]` and `.allowFragments` is pointless if the expected type is a collection type.

Comment: dictionaries can not be sorted,

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments a dictionary – a collection type containing key-value pairs – is unordered by definition, it cannot be sorted.

The `sorted` function of `collection` applied to a dictionary treats the dictionary for example

```
["foo" : 1, "bar" : false]
```

as an **array of tuples**

```
[(key : "foo", value : 1), (key : "bar", value : false)]
```

and sorts them by key `(.0)` or value `(.1)` (I suspect sorting by value `Any` will raise a compiler error)

The error occurs because you cannot assign an *array of tuples* to a variable declared as *dictionary*. That's almost the literal error message.

As a compromise I recommend to `map` the dictionary to a custom struct (similar to a tuple but better to handle)

```
struct Community {
    let key : String
    let value : Any
}
```

Your variable name already implies that you want a *real* array

```
var communityArray = [Community]()

let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as! Dictionary<String, Any>
communityArray = json.map { Community(key: $0.0, value: $0.1 }.sorted { $0.key < $1.key }
```

Comment: Not necessarily. If the struct is only used in the scope of a class you can even declare the struct within the class.

Comment: the communityArray will be used else where, its just being generated in one file.

Comment: Then you could use a separate file or declare it in the file outside the class where `communityArray` is populated.

Answer (score 0):

`sorted(by:)`  Returns the elements of the sequence, sorted using the given predicate as the comparison between elements, so you can not use as a dictionary.

For more info about this function you may read [sorted(by:) documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2298238-sorted)